# error: Invalid Parameter on every grub2 command

Tags: fedora, grub2

I just installed Fedora 28 by using live USB + anaconda installer on a ASUS tablet. Everything just works, but as this is a tablet, it would not have a keyboard attached to it under normal situations.

Upon every time it reboots, after grub2 counts down, it will show couple lines of message:

`error: invalid parameter.`

This would trigger a `--MORE--` prompt, thus preventing starting up without a keyboard attached.

By pure curiosity, I decided to take a look at my grub entry. Everything looks normal, nothing out of order. As I dropped into command prompt, I found out that every single command would produce this error message, even when a valid command is given.

I tried to reinstall grub2 by `dnf reinstall grub2-efi shim`, but the message is still there. Where shall I look for next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diving into source code of grub2 2.02, this error message `Invalid parameter` is thrown when grub2 attempts to call some functions related to TPM module.

Disabling TPM within this tablet's BIOS solved this problem.